# C# WPF XAML Run XAML Command on UserControl load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, modern-ui

I am trying to execute a XAML command, when the Usercontrol gets loaded.
The reason for that is that i want to change the theme of my application when the user navigates from Usercontrol A to Usercontrol B. I am using Firstfoor ModernUI.

The Code I want to execute:

```js
Command="mui:LinkCommands.NavigateLink"
         CommandParameter="cmd://settheme|/NLauncher;component/designs/ModernUI.BO2ii.xaml"
```

Usually u execute the Code with a button, but the user navigates with the TabControl included in the ModernUI.

Comment: If you have an event you can invoke a command with  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Load">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="

Comment: How can I trigger this event with C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

In your `<UserControl>` tag

Then use this piece of code

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourCommand}" CommandParameter = {Binding YourParameter} />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

You will need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` to your project

**Edit :** Fixed Event Name Load -> Loaded

Comment: How can I trigger this event with C#?

Comment: This is the [UserControl.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event. It is triggered the first time the UserControl is visible as stated on the doc

Comment: Its not working for me, maybe i there is sth missing in my XAML:
http://pastebin.com/7GLRP7dH (my complete XAML)

Comment: Your XAML seems fine. Maybe try to invoke a command you know will work (Like one that displays something)

Comment: I got it working, the event is "Loaded" not "Load" :)

Comment: Oops, my bad, you're right ! Edited for the next person coming here

Comment: Feeling stupid, but where do I have to place it in XAML exactly? in `UserControl.Resources`?

Answer (score 0):

Just added full XAML codes with reference to above answered code of Lionel Pire.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.MyClass"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             >
<Grid  Name="mygrid">

</Grid>


<!--Use this below the grid in case any control is passed in command parameter-->
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding myCommand}" 
                       CommandParameter = "{Binding ElementName=mygrid}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest package for XAML Interactions\Interactivity is now published as `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`

Install it via NuGet package manager:

`Install-Package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`

Sample usage:

`xmlns:behaviors="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"`

```
<Border>
    <behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
        <behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
        </behaviors:EventTrigger>
    </behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
</Border>
```